# How to replicate rows based on value of a column in same pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, replication

I need to do some row replication.
I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| label | count |
| --- | --- |
| HA1 | 5 |
| HA2 | 3 |
| HA3 | 1 |
| HA4 | 4 |

What I'm looking to do is to replicate every row by the number in the 'count' column.  So the output should look like this:

[image]

To be honest, I'm not a coder and so am trying to do this on a much larger dataset.  Hoping to get some ideas from this community.

Thanks.

-Big_Ears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `reindex` + `repeat`

```
out = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['count']))
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This worked.  Going to mark this as done.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative by using df.values

```
import pandas as pd
out = pd.DataFrame(df.values.repeat(df['count'], axis=0), columns=df.columns)
```